# getting rid of spaces (%20) in resulting anchor

Tags: html

I have a Local HTML document that I want to have an Anchor Tag (`<a>`) open a Website, however the URL Code being sent is

```
http://www.my%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20firerules.net/
```

which apparently has 8 embedded spaces for some reason.

Here is the call (from within a Table (`<tb>`) in the HTML document):

```
<a href="http://www.myfirerules.net" target="_blank">MFR.net Link</a>
```

The new browser window is opened, however the Address being opened is:

```
[http://www.my%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20firerules.net/]
```

rather than

```
[http://www.myfirerules.net]
```

as the `href=` says to do.

Can anyone tell me how to correct this?

Answer (score 0):

First off, your link above (before the question was edited) was written as:

```
<"a href="http://www.myfirerules.net" target="_blank">MFR.net Link<"/a">
```

Did you mean:

```
<a href="http://www.myfirerules.net" target="_blank">MFR.net Link</a>
```

---

Secondly, if you have linebreaks and/or indentation in the *middle* of your `href` attribute in the actual code, this could result in the spaces being included in the destination URL.